# Android cannot rotate emulator on mac power book

Tags: android

I tried every key combination and on my mac it will not rotate, i can rotate it on my windows computer,
i tried command arrow keys, ctrl arrow keys, option arrow keys, command f11, f11 and a bunch of other key combinations.

Is there a way to do this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use,

**Fn+Ctrl+F12**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. as standard function keys?

1. Go into **System Preferences**.
2. Click **Keyboard**.
3. Check **Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably already tried but: **Cmd+F12**?